# search class member function using GNU Global

Tags: c++, gnu-global

How to search member function of a class using GNU Global?

For example, there're two classes

```
class A{
func();
...};

class B{
func();
...}
```

If I search func, both A::func and B::func appears. If I search "A::func", nothing is returned.